# Why does LogBoxStateSubscription cause commits in the React dev tools profiler?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-devtools

I am trying to profile my React Native app, but LogBoxStateSubscription seems to create commits when profiling:

[image]

I have not seen this before - how can I stop this so I only see commits caused by my React source code rendering?

I have tried to use `LogBox.ignoreAllLogs();` but it doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: Have you found any solution to this issue?